# Header menu size not responsive

Tags: css, html

Hi I downloaded a template, I edidted the css just by adding the "fixedheader" to make the logo inside the header-wrap which look like this [image: image 1]. but when I resize the window to a min-width the header does not respond but instead "fixedheader" height still 180px, which look like this [image: image 2]. I tried to remove the "fixedheader" to make the height of header-wrap will not make the height too high which look like this [image: image 3] as you can see the height of the white background just only include half of the logo. Is there any way to fix this, I am feeling confuse, you can check the style.css at https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvhc59qtk5z2ns9/style.css?dl=0 . Here is the header from index.html

```
<header id="header" class="transparent-header" data-sticky-class="not-dark">

            <div id="header-wrap" class="fixedheader ">

                <!-- Primary Navigation  
                ============================================= -->
                <nav id="primary-menu" class="style-2 center">

                    <div class="container clearfix"></div>

                        <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                        <ul class="one-page-menu" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="65" >
                            <li><a href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html"><div>WHO WE ARE</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="products.html"><div>WHAT WE TRADE</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html"><div>SERVICES</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="logistic.html"><div>LOGISTICS</div></a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html"><div>CONTACT</div></a></li>  
                        </ul>
                </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->
                <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->

                <div id="logo" class="divcenter">
                    <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark@2x.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
                </div><!-- #logo end -->

            </div>


        </header><!-- #header end -->
```

Comment: please add that template URL or your site URL.

Comment: @RenishKhunt here is the link https://themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/9228123?s_rank=2

Comment: @vel I uploaded it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvhc59qtk5z2ns9/style.css?dl=0 .

Comment: if i create fiddle with above css and your posted html its not responsive and there no space.

Comment: @vel you can remote my pc if you want

Comment: @vel can I have your email so that I can send the details then after you can remove your email. is that ok?

Comment: @vel ok I got your email address I will talk to you on gmail

Comment: @vel Thank you so much \m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css.

```
@media(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #logo {
        float: none !important;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
    .fixedheader {
        min-height: 100px;
    }
}
```